# GDB crashing in Eclipse on longjmp

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gdb, setjmp

I am using c in eclipse to write a program. I need to use GDB to debug it step by step. However on a longjmp command (when i try to save the context of a stack) GDB crashes inside eclipse (because there is a breakpoint there?) Is there any way around this? I have scoured the internets for the past six hours and cannot seem to be able to find a solution. Here is the line of code where it is crashing

```
if(setjmp(p->jbContext) == 0)
    longjmp(context_buf,1);
```

I would be very very grateful to anyone that can help.

Thanks!

EDIT: After further searching I found this webpage but have no clue as to how to use it.

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_271.html

Assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: If `gdb` crashes then there's a bug waiting to be reported.

Comment: What does the crash look like?

Answer (score 0):

If it is really `gdb` which crashes, you could consider (after reporting the bug to them) install a newer version of it. Latest [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) is version **7.3.1** -you can compile it from its source code if needed. If you are brave and the bug persists with the latest version, try to find the bug and propose a patch.

My experience with gdb crashes (which are rare) is that getting and building the newest version helps a lot. Many Linux distributions don't ship a very recent GDB.

Of course, you might need to upgrade your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler also: the debugging information that is generated has also improved.